# Accessing route and POST params in Web Api 2 Controller Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a controller that needs access both route and POST body parameters. However when I use this implementation

```
public class MessageController : ApiController
{
    [Route( "Data/Message/{apiKey}/{userId}" )] 
    [HttpPost]
    public Message Post( Guid apiKey, string userId, [FromBody] string message)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

the `message` argument is always `null`.

How can I access all the apropos data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FromBody] parameters must be encoded as value

don't you try to do this:

```
public Message Post( Guid apiKey, string userId, [FromBody] string message)
{
    // ...
}
```

try this instead

```
 public Message Post( Guid apiKey, string userId, [FromBody] string value)
 {
    // ...
 }
```

and use this kind of code to do POST request with jquery:

```
  $.post('YourDomain/Data/Message/{apiKey}/{userId}', { '': value });
```

for more detail, here is the link http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies my confusion about [FromBody]. However, is there a way to mix route & POST data together in the method parameters such as ``public Message Post( Guid apiKey, string userId, Models.Message message)`` where ``apiKey`` and ``userId`` come from the routing and ``message`` maps the post body parameters?

Comment: what about you include all that parameter into a class?

Comment: Ok, so I actually gave this a try. I was hasty in confirming this. This does not work. The route params will not to identically named properties in a class, let alone the route params + post params.