# Using both route and POST params in Web Api controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

How can I set up an `ApiController` so that I can bind the method parameters to both a parameterized route and the request parameteres (in this case a POST, but PUTs as well)?

Something along the lines of

```
public class MessageController : ApiController
{
    public class Message
    {
       public string Content { get; set; }
       public int Priority { get; set; }
    }

    [Route( "Data/Message/{apiKey}/{userId}" )] 
    [HttpPost]
    public Message Post( Guid apiKey, string userId, Message msg)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

So that this would work

```
$.post('/Data/Message/<some key>/<some id>', { 
    Content: 'Did you receive my payment?', 
    Priority: 0 
 });
```

I tried the method from [Accessing route and POST params in Web Api 2 Controller Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771329/accessing-route-and-post-params-in-web-api-2-controller-method/25798476#25798476) of using a class and having the parameters bound to its properties, but this does not work. The parameter is simply always `null`.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `[FromBody]` attribute

```cs
[Route("Data/Message/{apiKey}/{userId})]
[HttpPost]
public Message Post(Guid apiKey, string userId, [FromBody] Message msg)
{
    ...
}
```

Then your `Message` class property names should match your javascript data object.

```js
var data = {
    Content: 'Did you receive my payment?',
    Priority: 0
};

$.post('/Data/Message/<some key>/<some id>', data);
```